# Moved a WordPress install from an old directory into root directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that was installed in a /wordpress/ folder, so when you try to access the website it will look like www.example-domain.com/wordpress/

The problem is recently  I decided to move it to the root directory so that the site can be accessed by just going to the www.example-domain.com

So what I did first is download SQL dump, then delete the old installation of WordPress, installed a fresh one and overwrite the Database using SQL dump.
Everything went well, but when I tried to view the site this came up.

[image: The styling is gone]

And I also noticed that whenever I tried to access to the dashboard through www.example-domain.com/wp-login.php

It will say that it is missing

> The requested URL /wordpress/wp-login.php was not found on this
>   server.

So I am under the impression that it still points to the old installation.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login to the database and manually edit 2 entries. In the `wp_options` table you can find `siteurl` and `home`. Update those appropriately, you should then be able to login properly.

You also need to update your `.htaccess` file but if you edit your permalink options and then change them back this should rewrite it for you.

For future reference to simply change directory of your installation if you login to the WP admin and go to Admin -> Settings -> General you can change the Wordpress Address and Site Address (the options you changed manually in the database) there. Once changed simply copy the entire installation folder to the new location and that will be it. It's easier to make the changes before you move it than after.

Comment: thank you the Themes is now working fine. Although I noticed one thing, the images in the Media is still pointed towards the old site and is not displaying.

Comment: If you do a google search for "update wordpress image locations after move" there are many plugins that can scan your database and replace the URL for you. If you know SQL syntax you can also try it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Update the table `wp_options` for  `siteurl` and `home` with respective values.

Also change `.htaccess` file

Comment: I have the .htacess what will I do with it?

Comment: Yes but I'm having trouble with the images/ Media content. They are still pointing towards the previous site-url.

Comment: Then for that you have to find and replace that URLs in database.if in your theme you have a options like custom image uploads for slider,social-icon then you can edit it directly from admin side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a couple of paths in the database to the new directory.

try to search for records that include "/wordpress" and remove it.

This solved a similar problem for me.